# Function returns type

Tags: php

Why the return type `"integer"` throws a fatal error. If I remove the type `"integer"` in the function, I will get 1.

```
 function add(int $a, int $b): integer {
        return $a + $b;
    }
    echo add(5.7, -4.6);
```

> faultCode1faultStringFatal error:Uncaught TypeError: Return value of add() must be an instance of integer, integer returned in

Comment: replace integer with int

Comment: Also 5.7 and -4.6 are not integers.

Comment: What I didn't realise is that if you don't declare strict_types, scalar type hint arguments and returns with type mismatches don't necessarily throw an exception if coercion can occur.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `int` instead of `integer`
Please try this:

```
function add(int $a, int $b): int 
{
    return $a + $b;
}
```

Another problem that you have is: 5.7 and -4.6 are not integers value, so your code isn't valid and you get an exception for this

[Type hint documentation](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/scalar_type_hints_v5)

Comment: Try to Change the parameters $a and $b from int to Integer!

Comment: Is the choice of linking to the RFC rather than the manual,  because the latter is thin on detail here?

Comment: You won't get a TypeError fatal error if not in strict mode for those argument hint mismatches.

Comment: yeah is correct! Thanks @Progrock
however the choice to link rfc is that is more specific I think and you could understand well the problem